# Simple Node Program Stops Working

Tags: c++, list, nodes

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct ListNode{

    string item;
    int count;
    ListNode *link;
};

typedef ListNode* ListNodePtr;

int main(){

    ListNodePtr head;

    head->count = 3;
    head->item = "dog";
    head->link = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Hi I'm really new to nodes and I can not figure out why this program stops working. It will compile and run but then it crashes. It's probably super obvious but, like I said, I'm a baby when it comes to nodes.

Comment: You've declared "head" as a pointer - it needs to point to something - see "new"

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I changed {ListNodePtr head;} to {ListNodePtr head = new ListNode;} and it seems to be working.

Comment: Just a small thing, but in this early stage where you're just getting your feet wet with pointers, I'd suggest against typedefing them away. Stick to ListNode* to make the fact that it is a pointer in your face.

Comment: Wait until the pointer arithmetic comes into play!